# Merging two array objects of different lengths on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, lodash

I'm needing some help with a rather straight-forward but challenging (for me :) programming task.

There are two array objects, one long and one short:

```
var arrayShort = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    name: 'first'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'second'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'third'
  }
]

var arrayLong = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub1'
  },{
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub2'
  },{
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub3'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub1'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub2'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub3'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub1'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub2'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub3'
  }
]
```

**How might I merge them together, based on shared ids, to get the following:**

```
var arrayCombined = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    name: 'first'
  },{
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub1'
  },{
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub2'
  },{
    id: 'A',
    name: 'firstSub3'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'second'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub1'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub2'
  },{
    id: 'B',
    name: 'secondSub3'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'third'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub1'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub2'
  },{
    id: 'C',
    name: 'thirdSub3'
  },
]
```

#### Important

Order is important.

#### What I've tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayShort.length; i++) {
  var itemShort = arrayShort[i]
  console.log(itemShort)
  for (var j = 0; j < arrayLong.length; j++) {
        var itemLong = arrayLong[j]
    if (itemLong.id === itemShort.id) {
      console.log(itemLong)
      arrayShort.splice(j + 1, 0, arrayLong)
    }
  }
}


var arrayCombined = arrayShort
console.log(arrayCombined)
```

This results in an infinite loop, though I'm not sure why. Generally, I know that nested loops and conditionals are bad news.

**What would be a better way to approach this (mentally, with code, etc)?**

[Here's a Codepen](http://codepen.io/isaacgregson/pen/ByMPKv), open dev tools to see

**Notes:**

- Vanilla Javascript solutions preferred, but it'd also be good to see ways of doing this with Lodash or Underscores.  Generally, I sense that either of those two libraries could make this type of task super easy, but I can't ever seem to get my head around exactly how.
- Trying to find the right search terms for this has been surprisingly difficult... suggestions?

Grateful for feedback/insights.

Comment: Since both lists seems to be sorted and in the same order, use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Comment: `arrayShort.splice(j + 1, 0, arrayLong)` is a bad idea. Better try constructing a new array, it's much easier and cleaner.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing me towards the merge algorithm. And yes, I *certainly* see that splicing, especially in a nested jungle, is a bad approach - hence my asking the question.

Comment: Also, it's likely important to point out that these are coming from the same big `json` blob, which I'm receiving and needing to parse into my desired data structure from an external API.

Comment: @IsaacGregson If you expect a big json blob, then I don't think you should go with the sorting approach. That is less code, but you ll pay with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concat and sort are your friends

```
var arrayCombined = (arrayShort.concat(arrayLong).sort(function(a,b) {


            return (a.id > b.id) ?  1 : 
                  ((a.id < b.id) ? -1 : 0);

})).sort(function(a,b) {

            return (a.name > b.name) ?  1 : 
                  ((a.name < b.name) ? -1 : 0);

});;

console.log(arrayCombined);
```

here is the output

```
[ { id: 'A', name: 'first' },
  { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub1' },
  { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub2' },
  { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub3' },
  { id: 'B', name: 'second' },
  { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub1' },
  { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub2' },
  { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub3' },
  { id: 'C', name: 'third' },
  { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub1' },
  { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub2' },
  { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub3' } ]
```

Comment: Note: This is highly inefficient. Since it has to do O(N lg N) sorting on a large data set.

Comment: After working for a while implementing this approach, I've noticed here (and in my results) that `second` and `third` are not at the top of their lists... meaning this approach *doesn't* work! As I mentioned in the question, **order is important**. Ideas?

Comment: UPDATE :  first sort by id then by the other property

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash, you can do something like this:

```
var arrayShort = [
    { id: 'A', name: 'first' },
    { id: 'B', name: 'second' },
    { id: 'C', name: 'third' }
];

var arrayLong = [
    { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub1' },
    { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub2' },
    { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub3' },
    { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub1' },
    { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub2' },
    { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub3' },
    { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub1' },
    { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub2' },
    { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub3' }
];

_(arrayShort)
    .union(arrayLong)
    .sortByAll('id', 'name')
    .value()
// →
// [
//   { id: 'A', name: 'first' },
//   { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub1' },
//   { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub2' },
//   { id: 'A', name: 'firstSub3' },
//   { id: 'B', name: 'second' },
//   { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub1' },
//   { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub2' },
//   { id: 'B', name: 'secondSub3' },
//   { id: 'C', name: 'third' },
//   { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub1' },
//   { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub2' },
//   { id: 'C', name: 'thirdSub3' }
// ]
```

Where [union()](https://lodash.com/docs#union) is a cheap way to concatenate two arrays without side-effects in either one, and [sortByAll()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortByAll) lets you sort by multiple property names.

Comment: +1. I had arrived at this same approach before seeing this. Why? Mostly because I had some other relation (sub-sub-sections) that needed to be included, for which Lodash's `flatten` does wonders.